# Maven Assembly Exclusion of Dependencies suddenly dont work.

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have had a project set up for the past year or so and have been using the maven assembly plugin to package the jar.

```
     <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>myProject</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/project.xml</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have been using the project.xml descriptor to specify the exclusions of the jar as follows:

```
   <assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
<id>project</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
            <exclude>commons-io:commons-io</exclude>
            <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
            <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
            <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
            ...
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

This has been working fine. My jar would be packaged perfectly, excluding the dependencies that it was supposed to and would end up only being around 850KB by the end of everything. So today I go to package my jar as normal after doing some updates and none of the exclusions are being applied, and my final Jar is at about 12MB. This was quite alarming and frankly annoying. The thing is I have done absolutely nothing to the pom.xml. I back up my eclipse workspaces every night and I went to back to what I had yesterday (which I know produced a 850KB jar) and its the same result, a 12MB jar. Is there any sort of thing that would change this. An update of some kind? Anything?

Comment: I suggest you start investigating by looking at what is in the 12MB jar. That will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: What is in my 12MB jar are all the dependency jars specified in the exclusions of my project.xml assembly file, along with the jars I did not want to exclude. This is my question, why arent my exclusions being excluded

Comment: You have two assembly descriptors listed... What does zip.xml look like? Also, have you considered using the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)?

Comment: Ugh I found my mistake! I had created a small command line project from one of the dependencies that was involved with this project. I guess leaving the build in that pom had somehow affected this one so that it would not work properly. Now I feel stupid :( thanks for the respones